# When a flexbox has two children with scrollable content, can I control them to take 50% height

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox

I have a flexbox container with a restricted/fixed height.
There are two children inside, they both have scrollable(dynamic) content.

When they both have content I would like them to take as much space as needed.
But when they both have more content (more than would fit 50%) I would like them to equally share the space. One container can only grow bigger than 50% when the other has no or only a few lines of content.

[image]

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p class="text-body">
      <!-- long, dynamic content -->
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p class="text-body">
      <!-- long, dynamic content -->
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check my example:
https://codepen.io/fabiandarga/pen/oywZqp

Is this even possible?

Comment: Probably not  (at least with flex properties).....you want both to expland as much as possible but only in certain circumstances which kinda makes this conditional and CSS doesn't do that very well.

Comment: As @Paulie_D said, this isn't really feasible with CSS. CSS is unable to be aware of content in elements outside of the current one (e.g. siblings, ancestors, etc). The closest solution - without resorting to JS - would be to impose max-height: 50%.